# How Can I Get My Player Animation To Remain Flipped After Turning?

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I have a player character in Unity with two separate animations. The first is the body moving, and the second is the character's face moving. These two are not made as a single animation because they move independently of each other, so I've got the body on one anim controller and the face on separate one (the face game object is a child of the body). Both are set to trigger when going from idle to run, and return back from run to idle. But I'm currently running into an issue:

I have the character's face sprite set to right-facing, so it defaults to facing right. When the character moves left, the face will move left as I want it to, but it snaps back to facing right when input ceases. I realized that this happens because the animation for the face to move left uses a flip.x keyframe, and because the face sprite is defaulting to right-facing, it switches back afterwards because the animation doesn't loop. What I want is for the face to remain left-facing even after left input ceases. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?